# Google Chrome silent install

Tags: windows, shell, google-chrome

I need to silent install Google Chrome on virtual machine. (Windows 8.1)
I took the standalone installer from https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?system=true&standalone=1#eula. 
On virtual machine in terminal I perform the command - 'ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe'.
At the end on installation I got the window with 'Close' button.
[image]

Is there command line switch for Google Chrome to perform silent installation?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to perform silent install with .msi file.

First go and download msi to : https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?msi=true

Second create a text file called install.cmd and copy in the following command lines:

```
@echo install Google Chrome
start /wait msiexec /i "%~dp0%googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi%" /qn /l*
```

Both save to a folder in your computer and "run as administrator" install.cmd file.

If you get error please see [silent install google chrome](http://www.get-itsolutions.com/silent-install-google-chrome-and-disable-auto-update/) tutorial for more information.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

Should be fairly straight forward, grab the MSI installer and use the following MSI command for a fully silent installation:

> msiexec.exe /i "GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi" /q /norestart

You can also make the following changes should you need them:

Change the /i to /x for uninstall
Change the /i to /f for a repair installation
Change the /q to /qb+ for the wizard to show but no user intervention apart from the final modal box at the end of the install

Remove the /norestart if you are happy for it to carry out a restart automatically

Source: https://blog.techygeekshome.info/2018/07/google-chrome-msi-installer-version-67-0-3396-99-release/

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/command-line-options

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution.

Run the standalone installer on a machine without Chrome (you should be able to Google for it). In your %TEMP% directory, look for something called GUM(something).tmp. Inside this directory will reside a file with a name like 154.48_chrome_installer.exe.{8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}.

Copy this file somewhere network accessible. Drop the GUID from the end, restoring its EXE extension. This is the silent installer- run it and Chrome will autoinstall.

If that is not where you looking for then maybe this article gives an answer to your question. 
http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/11/network-silent-unattended-install-of.html

Comment: A good solution - using Chocolatey (package manager for Windows). Command to silent Google Chrome installation: ```choco install googlechrome ```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my installation script:

`start "Installing Chrome Silently" /wait "ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe" /silent /install`

Requires chrome installer and script to be in the same directory, otherwise you'd need to specify the full path.  OFC, with this you still have a shell window, but no chrome window is ever visible.

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers were kind of halfway there for me.  I thought I'd share my accumulation of all the things that did work for me.  This works as of 7-5-19.

1. Download installer from this link: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?msi=true
2. Create a text file called install.cmd and copy in the following command lines:

   `@echo install Google Chrome
   start "Installing Chrome Silently" /wait "ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe" /silent /install
   @echo Set the parameter file
   @XCOPY "master_preferences" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\" /E /C /Q /R /Y`
3. Create a master_preferences file as outlined here:
   https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187948?hl=en
   Mine looks like this:

`{
"homepage" : "http://www.google.com",
"homepage_is_newtabpage" : false,
"browser": {
"show_home_button" : true,
"check_default_browser" : false
}
"bookmark_bar" : {
"show_on_all_tabs" : true
},
"distribution" : {
"skip_first_run_ui" : true,
"show_welcome_page" : false,
"import_search_engine" : false,
"import_history" : false,
"create_all_shortcuts" : true,
"do_not_launch_chrome" : true,
"suppress_first_run_default_browser_prompt": true,
"suppress_first_run_bubble": true,
"system_level": true,
"make_chrome_default" : false
}`

4. Put all the files in the same folder
5. Run install.cmd as admin.

[image]